# gradient border color with top side transparent

Tags: html, css

[image]

how to create border around an image with a gradient effect and border-top as transparent as seen in image

Comment: https://codepen.io/junaidcody/pen/yLxVzPG have a look

Answer (score 1):

set `linear-gradient` in  `border-image`.
Edit `linear-gradient` according to your need.

```css
div {
            height: 300px;
            width: 200px;
            border-image-source: linear-gradient(rgb(240, 240, 245), red);
            border-image-slice: 1;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 2px;
        }
```

```html
<div></div>
```